# Java associating two ArrayLists and printing out the results

Tags: java, arraylist, nested

what I have here is a set of three ArrayLists. An ArrayList of students which holds the name , surname , uid and degree scheme. Then I also have a list of modules and each module also holds an arraylist of student ID's for the students which are enrolled on that particular module.

What I'm trying to do is to link in the arraylist of students with the arraylist of the user ID's so the program would look at the ID's and compare them to the list which has all the student details and then write a combined report with the full student details and the modules which they are enrolled on.

I'm having my arraylists set up nicely, but I'm having difficulty accessing the inner arraylist with the ID's. It's quite tricky to explain but here is the code for my Application class that holds everything together, you can see how the ArrayLists are laid out.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Model {
    private ArrayList<Student> students;
    private ArrayList<Module> modules;
    private Module moduleLink;

    public Model(){
        students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        modules = new ArrayList<Module>();





    }
    public void runTests() throws FileNotFoundException{
        System.out.println("Beginning program, the ArrayList of students will now be loaded");
        loadStudents("studentlist.txt");
        System.out.println("Load attempted, will now print off the list");
        printStudents();
        System.out.println("The module list will now be loaded and printed");
        loadModules("moduleslist.txt");
        printModules();
        System.out.println("Modules printed, ArrayList assosciation will commence");






    }
    public void printStudents(){
       for(Student s: students){
           System.out.println(s.toString());
       }
    }

    public void printModules(){
        for(Module m: modules){
            System.out.println(m.toString());

        }

    }

    public void loadStudents(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner infile =new Scanner(new InputStreamReader 
                (new FileInputStream(fileName)));
        int num=infile.nextInt();infile.nextLine();
        for (int i=0;i<num;i++) {
            String u=infile.nextLine();
            String s=infile.nextLine();
            String n=infile.nextLine();
            String c=infile.nextLine();

            Student st = new Student(u,s,n,c);
            students.add(st);

        }
        infile.close();

    }   


    public void loadModules(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner infile =new Scanner(new InputStreamReader 
                (new FileInputStream(fileName)));
        int numModules = infile.nextInt();
        infile.nextLine();
        for (int i=0;i<numModules;i++){     

            String code = infile.nextLine();
            int numStudents = infile.nextInt();
            infile.nextLine();
            ArrayList<Student> enrolledStudents = new ArrayList<Student>(numStudents);


            for (int a=0;a<numStudents;a++){

                String uid = infile.nextLine();

                Student st = new Student(uid);
                enrolledStudents.add(st);

            }

            Module m = new Module(code,enrolledStudents );
            modules.add(m);

        }
        infile.close();
    }












}
```

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What's the concrete problem you're facing? Why don't you use a Map<String, Student>, to have each student by ID?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Student details, probably you should re-design your classes.
Student should be enrolled to a module. Hence, Student should have Module. And use a Map to retrieve students based on the id.

```
class Student {
    String id;
    List<Module> modules = new ArrayList<Module>();
}
```

loadStudents() would remain same except that you have to populate a Map of student id to Student objects you create in the loop.
loadModules() would then pick the student based on student id from the map and update the modules.

This would be the case where you need data based on Student.